# Move active windows to specific workspace activity with qdbus in KDE

Tags: kde, kwin

I'm using KDE plasma 5.6 with *multiple activities* and *multiple desktops*,
I'd to have some application instances bound to specific combination of activity and desktop, i.e. :

- Telegram client on desktop 5 of all activities
- PDF viewer on desktop 2 of activity "reading"
- Browser with RSS feed on desktop 1 of activity "reading"

I can set up some kwin rules to obtain this behavior but when matching the right window isn't straightforward rules aren't helping, 
this is happening with browser windows that change often theirs name based on the title of leftmost opened tab.

Manually moving around windows could become cumbersome.

I'm wondering if there are any `qdbus` methods that allow me to move currently active window to desktop and activities with specified id,
in order to bind this method to a key combination.

Keyboard shortcuts for moving windows around desktops and physical monitor already exist there are something also for activities?

Answer (score 1):

I did not see any methods defined in KWin's dbusinterface.h file, but I was able to set a shortcut in Global Keyboard Shortcuts, for Kwin, "Window to Desktop #" where # goes from 1 to 20.  I set mine to Ctrl+Alt+1 for Desktop 1.

Comment: I'm already using that, but this doesn't allow me to move windows through activities. It seems nothing has changed on this.